# How would you add chars to an array dynamically? Without the array being predefined?

Tags: c, arrays, char

If I want to add chars to char array, I must do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    char characters[7] = "0000000";
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        characters[i] = (char)('a' + i);
        if (i > 2) {
            break;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        printf("%c\n", characters[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To prevent from printing any weird characters, I must initialize the array, but it isn't flexible. How can I add characters to a char array dynamically? Just like you would in Python:

```
characters = []
characters.append(1)
...
```

Comment: ` char characters[7] = "0000000";` won't compile (if you are lucky) as `"0000000"` is an array of 8 characters including the null pointer at the end of the string. If you really want an array of 7 characters, use ` char characters[7] = {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0'}";`

Comment: @mattnz: `char a[7] = "1234567";` is perfectly OK in C. I understand it is an error in C++, but this post isn't tagged with that language and therefore your comment is misleading.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no non-ugly solution for pure C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    size_t space = 1;                  // initial room for string
    char* characters = malloc(space);  // allocate
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        characters[i] = (char)('a' + i);
        space++;                       // increment needed space by 1
        characters = realloc(characters, space); // allocate new space
        if (i > 2) {
            break;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        printf("%c\n", characters[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In practice you want to avoid the use of realloc and of course allocate the memory in bigger chunks than just one byte, maybe even at an exponetial rate. But in essence thats what happening under the hood of std::string and the like: You need a counter, which counts the current size, a variable of the current maximum size (Here it is always current size+1, for simplicity) and some reallocation if the need for space surpasses the maximum current size.

Comment: You haven't freed the memory!

Comment: @CJxD `return` from main implicitly frees all memory

Answer (score 4):

Yes, of course you can add characters dynamically:

```
quote char[100] = "The course of true love";
      strcat( quote, " never did run smooth.";
```

but only if there is enough room in quote[ ] to hold the appended characters. Or maybe you are asking why, in C, you have to pre-arrange enough character storage whereas, in Python, storage is allocated dynamically. That's how the language was designed in 197x.

[**C99**](http://wwwold.dkuug.dk/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n869/n869.txt.gz) *does* allow dynamically-allocated storage: storage allocated by the system at run time. And a very bad mistake it is, imo.

Comment: Why do you think it's a bad idea that dynamically-allocating storage ability was added in C99? I have no opinion on the matter, just curious ...

Comment: +1 - Thanks for making me aware of another mistake made by C99.  It's not really C.

Comment: @equality -- In case you don't know, dynamically-allocated storage in C99 is called "variable-length arrays" or VLAs. Just IMO: (1) VLAs are allocated on the stack rather than the heap, which makes it easy to blow up the stack by mistake and without warning. (2) 'sizeof' need not yield a constant anymore; I can take the 'sizeof' a VLA at run time. That confuses me and scares me. (3) Because C is no longer a subset of C++ -- no VLAs in C++ -- I can't compile/link my programs using a C++ compiler anymore; thus it's hard to port my C programs to C++. I agree with @Heath Hunnicutt: C99 is not C.

Answer (score -3):

You cannot unless you use [Linked Lists](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/103/) or some other custom data structure.