# Insert element into dynamic char array in C programming

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, char

I was having some problem when trying to add element to dynamic char array in C programming. Here is the expected output:

```
How many characters do you want to input: 5
Input the string:datas
The string is: datas
Do you want to 1-insert or 2-remove or 3-quit?: 1
What is the character you want to insert: a
Resulting string: adata
```

I already did those user input part in the main function and here is the code in main where I take in the string input, size and pass them to insert():

```
printf("How many characters do you want to input: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
str = malloc(n + 1);
printf("Input the string class: ");
scanf("%s", str);

case '1':
    printf("What is the character you want to insert: ");
    scanf(" %c", &input);
    insert(str, input, n);
    break;
```

And the part where my insert():

```
void insert(char *str, char input, int n) {
int i;
size_t space = 1;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    str[i] = (char)(input + i);
    space++;                       
    str = realloc(str, space); 
    if (i > 2) {
        break;
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%c", str[i]);
}
}
```

However, when I tried to print out the string from insert(), let's say I entered `'a'` to append to the first element of dynamic array with a size of 5, the result that I am getting is `abcd=`

I referenced from the [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905379/how-would-you-add-chars-to-an-array-dynamically-without-the-array-being-predefi) and I not sure how to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do people not check the return value of `scanf`?

Comment: Sorry but do you mean checking the input passing as parameter from main to insert()? I checked it and it was correct. Just that for example when I entered 'b', the output became bcde=. Then let's say q, the outout became qrst= etc etc

Comment: The function `scanf` returns a value - how successful it is. This should be checked to ensure that the relevant variable has been "filled in". People make typos and perhaps give them an opportunity to re-enter the data

Comment: (please read the manual page for `scanf` - http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf

Comment: Why are you continuously storing `input+i` into the `str` buffer? Since `input` is `a` of course you then get `b` (a+1), `c` (a+2), etc. And why continuously `realloc`? You know exactly how long the final string needs to be. Just `malloc` once and be done with it.

Comment: The accepted answer there doesn't make much sense to me. re-allocating inside the for loop seems nonsensical. I also do not see why you would always return after 2 if n can be aribtrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code - with the contract that the caller does the free bit! The caller calls it with `insert(&str, input, n)`

```
void insert(char **str, char input, int n) {

char* temp = *str;
int i;

*str = realloc(*str, n + 2); /* realloc first */

if(!*str) /* realloc failed */
{
    fputs("realloc failed", stderr);
    free(temp); /* Free the previously malloc-ed memory */
    exit(-1); /* Exit the program */
}

for (i = n; i >= 0; i--) {
    (*str)[i + 1] = (*str)[i]; /* Move all characters up */ 
}

(*str)[0] = input; /* Insert the new character */

printf("%s", *str); /* Print the new string */
}
```

Sorry about the formatting. That is left to the reader. I have not checked the algorithm but this does not leak memory

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works and thanks for the explanation too!

Comment: But short question, when you realloc the *str, the n is increase by 2. So can I assume that 1 space is for the new input whereas the other is for the '\0'?

Comment: One assumes that the null character is there already. We just need to shift it. So the +2 could be +1

Comment: I see I see. Thanks a lot for the helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
void insert(char **str, char input, int n) {

    char* temp = *str;
    int i;

    *str = realloc(*str, n + 2); /* realloc first */

    if(!(*str)) /* realloc failed */
    {
        fputs("realloc failed", stderr);
        free(temp); /* Free the previously malloc-ed memory */
        exit(-1); /* Exit the program */
    }

    for (i = n; i >= 0; i--) {
        (*str)[i + 1] = (*str)[i]; /* Move all characters up */ 
    }

    **str = input; /* Insert the new character */

    printf("%s", *str); /* Print the new string */
}
```

And pass `str` by reference using

```
insert(&str, input, n); /* Note the '&' */
```

Comment: This has a memory leak

Comment: Yes. Fixed it and also a bug. Thanks.

Comment: Not quite fixed - `realloc` can return a different address that is thrown away

Comment: @CoolGuy No. `realloc()` cannot magically update all pointers to `str`.

Comment: @FUZxxl, Ed Heal, Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for copying my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for the helps too! However, the solution seems exactly like Ed Heal's.

Comment: @Denise Actually, I wrote the code, Ed Heal copied it. My code had some problems. I fixed it and at that moment, Ed Heal posted his answer. You can have a look at the timestamps to verify it.

Comment: @CoolGuy Ah I see I see. Sorry about that! :( Still thanks a lot for the helps, really appreciated them!